# Multiple conditionalPanel. How do I make them 1 variable?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to make multiple plots of the grades of students, but every student has different courses. To make sure a different list of courses appears I used `conditionalPanel` as seen below.

```
selectInput("name", label = h3("Choose a name"),
  choices = list("Claire" = "Claire", "Thomas" = "Thomas", "Alex" = "Alex"),
  selected = "Claire"),
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.name == 'Claire'",
  checkboxGroupInput("cour1", "Courses",
    list("Biology", "Mathematics", "Chemistry", "English", "French"),
    selected = "Biology")
  ),
conditionalPanel(
  condition = "input.bedr == 'Thomas'",
  checkboxGroupInput("cour2", "Courses",
    list("Economics", "History", "English", "Spanish", "Geography "),
    selected = "Economics")
```

The problem is that every students now has his/her own course variable (`cour1`,`cour2`), but I don't want to make 20 or so  different codes (for every student) to make the graphs.

I tried to make one variable like this:

```
if (input$name == "Clair"){
    input$cour <- input$cour1
}
```

This gave the error:

> Attempted to assign value to a read-only reactivevalues object

Comment: Read about `renderUI()`, we are trying to make `checkboxGroupInput` choices dynamic based on selected student name.

Comment: I'm trying to find some information about `renderUI()` in combination with `conditionalPanel`. I can't find a site with a explanation, do you know a good source to learn about `renderUI()` @zx8754 ?

Comment: Here is the start - http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

Comment: I tried to change my code using that, but now I get an error:
Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1): y, colour, x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @zx8754 pointed out, this can be done with `renderUI()`.

A short explanation about `render UI()` can be found on http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

But what really helped me was this Youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUop-YfRAuw